# Struggling to mutate columns elegantly in tidyverse

Tags: r, for-loop, tidyverse, dplyr

I am working with PUMS data and I am using tidycensus to translate the values of certain columns. However, this adds a new column with structure: columnname_label. I want to use mutate to replace the original column with the new translated values in columnname_label. Here is example of my data frame:

```
df <-data.frame(Region= c(1,2,1,4,3,1), 
                Region_label = c("North", "South", "North", "West", "East", "North"),
                Broadband = c(0,1,0,0,0,1)
                Broadband_label = c("No","Yes","No","No","No","Yes")
                Hispeed = c(1,1,0,0,1,0)
                Hispeed_label = c("Yes", "Yes","No","No","Yes","No")
```

I know I can write out code like this using tidycensus:

```
library(tidyverse)

recode <- df %>% mutate(Region = Region_label) %>% mutate(Broadband = Broadband_label) %>% 
          mutate(Hispeed = Hispeed_label)
```

However, I have 66 columns that need to be matched to the "_label" columns. Is there a more elegant way to perform this instead of writing 66 mutate statements?

I have tried writing a loop using mutate_at, but it does not work.

```
subset1 <- grep('*label*',names(df),value = TRUE) 

name <- names(df)

for (i in subset1) {
  

final <- final_house %>% mutate_at(vars(matches(trimws(name,"right","\\_label"))),i) 

}
```

This does not work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  select(ends_with("label")) %>% 
  rename_with(~ gsub("_label","", .))
```

**Output**

```
  Region Broadband Hispeed
1  North        No     Yes
2  South       Yes     Yes
3  North        No      No
4   West        No      No
5   East        No     Yes
6  North       Yes      No
```

Answer (score 1):

First, select all columns, which end with `"label"`. Then you can extract the string until the first underscore (`_`) using a reprex.

```
df %>% 
  select(ends_with("label")) %>% 
  rename_with(~ str_extract(.x, "^[^_]+(?=_)"))
```

Note that you need `dplyr` version `1.0.0` or newer for that.

Answer (score 1):

Using `across` this assigns to each column whose name is X the column whose name is X_label.  If there can be columns that do not have a corresponding _label column then replace the first argument of `across` with `sub("_label$", "", subset1)` where `subset1` is defined in the question.

```
 df %>% 
   mutate(across(!ends_with("_label"), 
                 ~ cur_data()[[paste0(cur_column(), "_label")]]))
```

giving:

```
  Region Region_label Broadband Broadband_label Hispeed Hispeed_label
1  North        North        No              No     Yes           Yes
2  South        South       Yes             Yes     Yes           Yes
3  North        North        No              No      No            No
4   West         West        No              No      No            No
5   East         East        No              No     Yes           Yes
6  North        North       Yes             Yes      No            No
```

Note that the above is easy to do with just base R:

```
replace(df, sub("_label$", "", subset1), df[subset1])
```

or adding a pipeline:

```
df %>% replace(sub("_label$", "", subset1), .[subset1])
```